# Flexing five images across with padding

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: Design I want]

I am aware I can get five image across a page by setting each image as **width 20%** and using `flex-wrap: wrap`. But how do I evenly space the images?

I tried `justify-content: space-around;` but that looks ridiculous. Padding messes up the 20% width calculation. So what's a good tact? I don't want the images to look like they are stitched together. If there are six images, there will be a large gap to right of the 6th image. I think that's fine.

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 1em;
  /* I want five across with image spacing, how do I achieve this? */
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
</article>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qpm37wy5/5/

Comment: thanks @Michael_B... I like that solution. Though I can't rely on CSS grid in PrinceXML. Doh!! I also wonder it should or shouldn't perhaps collapse down to a couple of images across for mobile screens.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qpm37wy5/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would wrap the images in a tag to manage element width and image width separately. Then apply the `width` and `padding` onto the containing element. Set the `width` of `img` to auto, and `max-width` to 100% to prevent the images from stacking.

In addition, you can alter the number of images that display at different screen sizes by changing the wrapper class properties.

When it comes to flexbox, I always reach for [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)!

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flexbox .image {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.flexbox img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
<div class="image"><img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0e316e1a1e2a600d0b922cddb3a5c6c2"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0e316e1a1e2a600d0b922cddb3a5c6c2"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0e316e1a1e2a600d0b922cddb3a5c6c2"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0e316e1a1e2a600d0b922cddb3a5c6c2"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0e316e1a1e2a600d0b922cddb3a5c6c2"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0e316e1a1e2a600d0b922cddb3a5c6c2"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0e316e1a1e2a600d0b922cddb3a5c6c2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry to be fussy, but is there a way to do it without the "image" class? Also I am hesitant to drop in `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` into my CSS for fear of it .... cascading ;)

Comment: @hendry In my far-from-comprehensive experience, flexbox works better with extra containers. Are you saying you prefer not to use child containers or that you are unable to use child containers? As for `border-box`, I do understand the reluctance to make such a change to an entire project, but it is quite standard to use. If you wanted to be safe, perhaps changing the rule to limit it to the container would be wise. I'm afraid it is necessary in this implementation due to the `width:20%` calculation. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for details.

Comment: More of a preference not to use child containers. It's sad that CSS for styling, requires bloat on the semantics of the HTML document! :/

Comment: @hendry you could wrap them in a `figure` instead of a `div` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the borders of the images to be aligned with the borders of the container and not offset by the padding, I would opt for a solution that relies on one sided margin, but that does not apply to the last item of each row.
Considering a row count of 5 items, and an image to image margin of 1% of the container's width, with the following DOM structure:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/unee-t-staging/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto,h_500,w_500/Unee-T%20inspection%20report%20-%20placeholder%20images/table_succulent.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Apply the following styles:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container div {
  max-width: 19.2%; /* (100 - ((items_per_row - 1) * 1) / (items_per_row)*/ 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.flex-container div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-container div:not(:nth-child(5n)) { /* matches number of items per row */
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

Example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEKmdG

Disclaimer: I'm working with @hendry on the same project...